# One subject, compound object phrases - comma or no comma?

Tags: punctuation, clauses, objects, gerund-phrases

My question is about how to punctuate sentences like the following:

> The system allows searching for variables using their long name and cryptic variable names and filtering the data sets based on a given variable availability.

subject: *the system*

main verb: *allows*

object 1 (gerund+participial phrase?): *searching for variables using their long name and cryptic variable names*

object 2 (gerund+past-participle-phrase?): *filtering the data sets based on a given variability*

coordinating conjunction between object 1 and 2: the second of the two 'and' words

Because the second 'and' is not followed by a subject + verb, this sentence appears not to require a comma. However, the presence of the first 'and', plus the string of gerunds and nouns this sentence contains, might cause the reader to have difficulty identifying the second object phrase. I encounter many such sentences in the editing I do, but I'm loathe to rephrase too many of the ones that *might* cause confusion.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat Still potentially ambiguous. [The system] [allows] [searching] [variables using long or cryptic names and filtering data based on variable availability].  // The system allows (a) searching variables using long or cryptic names and (b) filtering data based on variable availability. (At least.) People may not be aware of the 'searching variables' usage, and suspecting jargon usages may assume that 'filtering data' might be a NP. // Ah, you've miscopied. 'searching variables' probably better corrected.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I didn't miscopy; I reworded, as noted. Filtering is part of the search process, so it doesn't much matter whether it is read as ***The system allows searching variables [using names and filtering data]*** or as
***The system allows [searching variables] and [filtering data].***

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat  'Searching X' and 'searching for X' are very different notions in standard English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: When you perform a search for a variable, you search the variables for a particular variable.

Comment: But OP chooses 'searching for X'.

Comment: To OP's question on how to punctuate, isn't it OK that we use a comma just before the second 'and'? //The system allows searching for variables using their long name and cryptic variable names, and filtering the data sets based on a given variable availability.//

Comment: @Ram Pillai I think that there's a  duplicate where it's said that weighty compound predicates may exceptionally have a comma before the 'and' for clarity (especially where there are other _and_'s). But that rephrasing is usually the better option.

Answer (score 1):

"using their long name and cryptic variable names" can be considered as parenthetical; it's not grammatically necessary to the sentence, so it could be placed in commas or brackets. The same could also apply to "based on a given variable availability", which could be set off, and should receive the same treatment as the first parenthetical. In both cases you have an operation (filtering or searching) and a method used to do it; the method can be set apart.

This would give: "The system allows searching for variables (using their long name and cryptic variable names) and filtering the data sets (based on a given variable availability)." It's perhaps not the most elegant punctuation (some people frown upon the overuse of brackets in formal written English), but is unambiguous, good enough for technical documentation, and logically separates the general operation from the specific details.

Failing that, it could be expressed as two sentences; list with bullet points; or other rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be definitive and eliminate ambiguity, I'd suggest:

> The system allows searching for variables using their long name or cryptic variable names, as well as filtering the data sets based on a given variable availability.

Comment: The comma followed by _as well as_ instead of _and_ **is** an improvement. But you've missed a further ambiguity (As well as filtering the data sets based on a given variable availability, the system allows searching for variables using their long name or cryptic variable names. vs The system allows searching for variables [by] filtering the data sets based on a given variable availability, as well as [by] using their long name or cryptic variable names.' I'd want two sentences.